# Service worker fetch event not listing root index.html

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am having trouble listing index.html document in my service worker fetch event. So if I open a new tab and go to my development server I see the document listed as a request URL in service worker fetch event listener.

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", e => {
  console.log(e.request.url);
});
```

and here is the output

[image]

Okay everything working as planned. But when I do a refresh of the page I don't see the root request or "/"
for index.html.

What I going on. I have already added a middleware on my server to ensure that the browser won't cache the root file

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.url === "/") {
    res.header("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    res.header("Pragma", "no-cache");
    res.header("Expires", 0);
  }

  next();
});
```

So here is the output after the first refresh
[image]

I am going nuts because I cannot understand what is going on. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be running into issues due to the request for `/index.html` (or `/`) being a navigation, and the browser's DevTools resetting the console log messages following a navigation.

In Chrome's DevTools, I'd recommend going to the Network tab, and checking the "Preserve log" box there:

[image: Chrome's Network panel, with "Preserve log" checked]

Comment: That was it. Thank you

Comment: Gods... Jeff, you've saved my day. This was pretty unintuitive thing to do from the Chrome developers. Especially when Firefox is showing the initial request correctly in the logs :)